# When a form has multiple inputs with the same name, how do you get the index of that element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that has multiple rows of the same information, like this:

```
<form>
   <input name="a[]">
   <input name="b[]">
   <input name="d[]">
   <input name="e[]">
   <br>
   <input name="a[]">
   <input name="b[]">
   <input name="d[]">
   <input name="e[]">
   <br>
   <input name="a[]">
   <input name="b[]">
   <input name="d[]">
   <input name="e[]">
   ...
</form>
```

I'm simplifying my needs to make it easier to explain. When someone updates an element on one row, I want to detect that that row was changed, and be able to programatically change the other inputs on the same row.

For example, if someone changes the second b[], i want to be able to programatically update the second c[].

It needs to be generic so it can run on any similar form. I've added a change event for every element in the form, but I'm not sure how to derive the index from each input. Like, how do I know its the "second" a[], and then how do I get the "second" b[]?

I'm imagining something like this:

```
  inputs = resultForm.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea')
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
     inputs[i].onchange = function(e) {
        //something like this is what I'm after
        row = this.name.index;
        
        document.getElementsByName("b[]")[row].value = "a form element in this row was clicked";
     }
  }
```

The only thing that comes to mind is to grab every "a[]" and loop through them to see if they match the "this", then every "b[]", then "c[]" until I find the element that changed, and use it's index to identify the row number.

That's challenging cause I need it to be a generic solution, my fields wont always be named a, b, c, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is on the window load event, I grab every INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA in the form. Then I loop through them, keeping track of how many elements I have by each name. 10 named "name" and 10 named "address". Using that number I add rowid attribute to each element. Then in the events I can just read that rowid attribute.

```
<form>
   <input name="a[]" rowid="1">
   <input name="b[]" rowid="1">
   <input name="d[]" rowid="1">
   <input name="e[]" rowid="1">
   <br>
   <input name="a[]" rowid="2">
   <input name="b[]" rowid="2">
   <input name="d[]" rowid="2">
   <input name="e[]" rowid="2">
   <br>
   <input name="a[]" rowid="3">
   <input name="b[]" rowid="3">
   <input name="d[]" rowid="3">
   <input name="e[]" rowid="3">
   ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the elements with that name in the form, from which the index can be found.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input', e => {
  const index = [].indexOf.call(
    e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll(`[name='${e.target.name}']`), e.target);
  console.log(index);
});
```

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/go9myu6k/1/)